# CSS Scale, then resize to original

Tags: javascript, math, transform, scale

I'm creating a "zoom" effect with a div with overflow:scroll. Here's my dillema:

I use the following:

```
$('#object').css({ 'transform':'scale(50)' });
```

Which works beautifully, but now I would like to mathematically resize the element to it's original width/height (keeping the scale at 50%, or whatever the value might be...)

```
$('#object').css({ 'width': ?+'px', 'height': ?+'px' });
```

Pretty sure this is a math issue, I can get close with the following:

```
new_width = parseInt(origWidth) + parseInt(Math.round(origWidth*((100-zoomScale)/100)));
new_height = parseInt(origHeight) + parseInt(Math.round(origHeight*((100-zoomScale)/100)));
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your math is wrong.

```
700 * 0.5 = 350
```

But... if `700` represent `50%`, then `100%` will be `1400` and not 700 + 350...

So:

```
700 * 2 = 1400
```

supose my vars are that the math to get the oposite keep zoom will be:

```
(1/0.5) * 700
```

The math formula will be:

```
(1/(zoomScale/100)) * originalValue
```

For the original values, you can use the `css` `width` or `height` they will still the pixel original value, the modified by zoom value will be the clientWidth, clientHeight, offsetWidth and offsetHeight element properties.

Comment: That works well, thanks.

Now, what if I want to upsize, let's say 150%?

Comment: (`1`/zoomScale/100))*originalValue where 1 is your scale factor, to 150%, change `1` to `1.5`. Don't forgot to accept the answer if it help you :)